# How does mongo handle a "find" query with a limit on a sharded collection when no sort is specified

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Say I have a collection `events` that is distributed across three shards. The shard key is `{ _id: 'hashed' }`

This collection will often times be empty, but during times high volume reaches millions of records. When the collection is not empty, I'd like to grab 10000 records to process, process them, and then delete those records. Then repeat this process until the collection is empty.

We don't care which events we grab. We'll process them all eventually, and the order we process them doesn't matter. So we run this command in Java to grab the events:

`MongoCursor<Document> eventsToProcess = eventsCollection.find().limit(10000).iterator();`

For the delete operation, we build an array of all the `_id`s we fetched, and then tell mongo to delete all documents in the collection whose `_id` is in that array.

In order to take advantage of sharding, it would be nice if this delete operation could be split up across the shards, with each shard deleting its portion of the `_id`s in parallel with the others.

But in order for this delete operation to be split across the shards evenly, the command to fetch 10000 records above would have to grab documents from the shards in roughly equal proportion.

The only documentation I can find in regards to this question is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#sorting): "If the result of the query is not sorted, the mongos instance opens a result cursor that "round robins" results from all cursors on the shards."

I think this statement probably answers my question, but I don't know what this means: "the mongos instance opens a result cursor that 'round robins' results from all cursors on the shards."

**Will the `find` query listed above grab records evenly from the shards? If not, is there a way to have mongo grab records evenly from the shards?**

Comment: You write, that you process **all** documents. Instead of deleting the documents afterwards, you could simply drop the entire collection and create a fresh new collection.

Comment: It would take too much time and resources to process all the available documents. Besides, this doesn't answer my question, which is asking how mongo handles this find query without sorting on a sharded collection.

Comment: You can simply run the query and then check which documents have beendet returned, I.e. from which shards.